# Accessing Multidimensional stdClass array in Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I think I have a special case. I think my array is formatted in such away that the conventional methods for accessing a stdClass are not going to work.

Before someone dings me for not checking the posting (which there are many) on this subject. I want to post that I have checked nearly everyone of them and here are a few links to prove it.

I have read them all. I have tried all of the suggestions for accessing the data. None of them has worked to day.

My data is formatted this way:

```
 Children::__set_state(array(
  'id' => NULL,
  'code' => NULL,
  'accld' => NULL,
  'fname' => NULL,
  'mname' => NULL,
  'lname' => NULL,
  'gender' => NULL,
  'dob' => NULL,
  'class' => NULL,
  'status' => NULL,
  'photo' => NULL,
  'allergies' => NULL,

'0' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
 'id' => '1039',
 'code' => '2383',
 'accId' => '32',
 'fname' => 'Loren',
 'mname' => 'M',
 'lname' => 'Cings',
 'gender' => '2',
 'dob' => '2005-10',
 'class' => '1',
 'status' => '1',
 'photo' => ',
 'allergies' => '',
                     )),

'1' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
 'id' => '1044',
 'code' => '6266',
 'accId' => '32',
 'fname' => 'Justin',
 'mname' => 'R',
 'lname' => 'Cings',
 'gender' => '1',
 'dob' => '2001-11',
 'class' => '15',
 'status' => '11',
 'photo' => ,
 'allergies' => '',
                     )),
```

My personal thoughts are that my data needs to be formatted like

```
    [0] => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(  .....
```

Because when I look at all the other posted arrays. The array number is in brackets verses single quotes.

In my model code, this is what is generating the array:

```
   public function populate($row) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        $this->$key = $value;
     }
  }
```

The only thing that pokes a hole in this theory is because I have another array that is generated by this same function and it can assess its values with $myarray->value.

Thanks for looking and for your thoughts.

**Answer**

I figured out the answer to this riddle.
I had to go back and change my model code.

From this:

```
public function accld($id) {

    $query = $this->db->get_where($this::DB_TABLE, array('accId' => $id));
    $result = $this->populate($query->result());
    return $result;

}
```

to this:

```
public function accld($id) {

    $query = $this->db->get_where($this::DB_TABLE, array('accId' => $id));

    $result = $this->populate($query->result('array'));
    return $result;

}
```

adding the 'array' argument converted the data returned from

what you see above to this

```
Children::__set_state(array(
 'id' => NULL,
 'code' => NULL,
 'accld' => NULL,
 'fname' => NULL,
 'mname' => NULL,
 'lname' => NULL,
 'gender' => NULL,
 'dob' => NULL,
 'class' => NULL,
 'status' => NULL,
 'photo' => NULL,
 'allergies' => NULL,
'0' => 
  array (
         'id' => '1161',
         'code' => '1784',
         'accId' => '124',
         'fname' => 'Diane',
         'mname' => '',
         'lname' => 'Gre',
         'gender' => '1',
         'dob' => '2012-6',
         'class' => '18',
         'status' => '7',
         'photo' => 
      ));
```

Then I could just iterate through it with a

```
   foreach($children as $key => $val){ if(!empty($val)){
```

Comment: I don't think the links to prove it are necessary...question is long enough as it is

Comment: I know what you mean but if someone thinks I have not done my research then it can cost me point. Just trying to keep the nay Sayers down.

Comment: If you have found a solution, go ahead and post it as an answer and accept it. Please don't post the answer in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you figured out how to make it work, I'm not sure you're understanding why. Codeigniter returns an array of objects unless you specify it to return an array.

For example if you received an array like

```
$result = array(array('id'=>1,'name'=>'Steve','age'=>22) );
```

Using the 'array' argument, without it the standard code igniter return could be accessed with object notation in its default format, for example -  you would access the name in the first result row like this

```
$name = $result[0]->name;
```

I hope that makes sense and clears it up a bit for you.

Comment: I had to read it a few times but now I understand the light bulb has been turned on!!!! I feel like Neo now that I come to the Merovingian with the why...

Comment: Haha, glad I could help, had a hard time putting it into words. Glad someone understood what I meant. even after a couple read throughs.